# How to create a SQL query to join 3 tables

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables Client, User, UserAssociation:-
Need to display ClientName, UserName with respect to UserAssociation

Client

```
ClientID | Name
   1     | xyz
   2     | abc
```

User

```
UserId | UserName
   20  |   Sam
   21  |   Tony
```

UserAssociation

```
ClientId | UserId | UserAssociationId
   1     |   20   |         1
   2     |   21   |         2
```

How to Display

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What do you want? Show us the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way

```
SELECT UserAssociationId,
   Name AS ClientName,
   UserName
FROM   userassociation
   INNER JOIN USER
           ON User.userId = userassociation.userId
   INNER JOIN Client
           ON Client.clientId= userassociation.clientId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query below with alias, it will produce your desired output :

```
Select UserAssociationId,UserName as UserName
from UserAssociation UA
inner join User U on U.UserId  = UA.UserId
inner join Client C on C.ClientID = UA.ClientID;
```

Output on MySQL workbench:

```
UserAssociationId UserName ClientName

1    Sam     xyz

2    Tony    abc
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You may want all the clients regardless if they have a username or not, or the other way. If you want all clients with a Username then you would use an INNER join instead:

```
Select Client.clientId, Client.Name, User.UserId, User.Username
from Client
left join UserAssociation on UserAssociation.ClientId = Client.ClientId
left join User on UserAssociation.UserId = User.UserId;
```